# Get max value of 3 columns from pandas DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, max

I've a Pandas DataFrame with 3 columns:

```
c={'a': [['US']],'b': [['US']], 'c': [['US','BE']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(c, columns = ['a','b','c'])
```

Now I need the max value of these 3 columns.

I've tried:

```
df['max_val'] = df[['a','b','c']].max(axis=1)
```

The result is `Nan` instead of the expected output: `US`.
How can I get the max value for these 3 columns? (and what if one of them contains `Nan`)

Comment: By max value do you mean the value that occurs the most in all the 3 columns?

Comment: @Junkrat Yes, that's correct (I expect `US` as result.

Comment: Dataframes are not designed to work with lists in each cell, can you solve this problem by getting the data in another format? This way we can apply the more optimal methods provided by pandas / numpy instead of writing for loops.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
c={'a': [['US', 'BE'],['US']],'b': [['US'],['US']], 'c': [['US','BE'],['US','BE']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(c, columns = ['a','b','c'])
                  
            
from collections import Counter
df = df[['a','b','c']].apply(lambda x: list(Counter(map(tuple, x)).most_common()[0][0]), 1)
print (df)
0    [US, BE]
1        [US]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Quite close i think. If I change the DataFrame `c={'a': [['US','BE']],'b': [['US']], c: [['US','BE']]}` I expect the max value as ['US','BE']

Comment: @JohnDoe - hmmm, sorry, not understand. Why it is max value?

Comment: By max value I mean the value that occurs the most in all the 3 columns

Comment: So he basically wants the list which occurs the most.

Comment: The value that occurs the most from all lists (as if it was just one list) It can be one like `[US]` or multiple like `['US','BE']`

Comment: @JohnDoe - Can you check now?

Comment: Almost, It can't handle `NaN`. `c={'a': [[]],'b': [['US'],['US']], 'c': [['US','BE'],['US','BE']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(c, columns = ['a','b','c'])`

Comment: @JohnDoe - I dont understand, in comment above failed creating DataFrame, if use `c={'a': [[], []],'b': [['US'],['US']], 'c': [['US','BE'],['US','BE']]}` it return empty lists, because all 3 values has same 1 occurence.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you have some elements as a list type, So I think the below-mentioned code will work fine.

1. First, append all value into an array
2. Then, find the most occurring element from that array.

```
from scipy.stats import mode
arr = []

for i in df:
    for j in range(len(df[i])):
        for k in range(len(df[i][j])):
            arr.append(df[i][j][k])
            
from collections import Counter

b = Counter(arr)
print(b.most_common())
```

this will give you an answer as you want.

Comment: my final data frame contains more than these three columns. I have only listed 3 for the question.

Comment: I think it will work fine in multiple columns too otherwise you can use
print(b.most_common()[0][0]) this in final line

Answer (score 0):

if it as @ Erfan stated, most common value in a row then `.agg()`, `mode`

```
df.agg('mode', axis=1)
         0
0  [US, BE]
1      [US]
```

Answer (score 0):

while your data are lists, you can't use `pandas.mode()`. because lists objects are unhashable and `mode()` function won't work.
a solution is converting the elements of your dataframe's row to strings and then use `pandas.mode()`.
check this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> c = {'a': [['US','BE']],'b': [['US']], 'c': [['US','BE']]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(c, columns = ['a','b','c'])
>>> x = df.iloc[0].apply(lambda x: str(x))
>>> x.mode()
# Answer:
0    ['US', 'BE']
dtype: object
>>> d = {'a': [['US']],'b': [['US']], 'c': [['US','BE']]}
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(d, columns = ['a','b','c'])
>>> z =  df.iloc[0].apply(lambda z: str(z))
>>> z.mode()
# Answer:
0    ['US']
dtype: object
```